# Are questions about specific animals on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently created an area 51 topic titled Animals, which I intended to be used for asking questions about specific animals and their habitats, life expediencies, behavior patterns etc.

Are such specific questions about animals on topic here, or would they be better suited to the Animals proposal?

Comment: Animal behaviour and zoology broadly fall within ecology, environment and behavioural biology. So they'd b most welcome here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions about zoology are on-topic here, this looks like it would cover your proposal from your description. Questions about keeping animals, pets or similar would be off-topic.

Comment: Thanks Mad Scientist, I guess my animals proposal isn't needed after all.